# Typedef a shared_ptr type with a static custom deleter, similar to unique_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, raii

I have read through many questions on SO on custom deleter for `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`, and the difference between the two. But, I still haven't found any clear answer to this question:

How can one best go about creating a type that acts as a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter, similar to how `unique_ptr` has the deleter as part of the type definition?

For `unique_ptr` usage, I use a deleter class, that handles deletion of individual types (limiting it to just two types, for brevity):

```
struct SDL_Deleter {                                
  void operator()( SDL_Surface* ptr ) { if (ptr) SDL_FreeSurface( ptr );} 
  void operator()( SDL_RWops* ptr )   { if (ptr) SDL_RWclose( ptr );} 
};

using SurfacePtr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Deleter>;
using RWopsPtr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_RWops, SDL_Deleter>;
```

Which can be used with something like

```
SurfacePtr surface(IMG_Load("image.png"));
```

And will call `SDL_FreeSurface` upon destruction.

---

This is all fine and well. However, how does one go about achieving the same for `shared_ptr`? Its type is defined as

```
template< class T > class shared_ptr;
```

and the way to provide a custom deleter is through the constructor. It doesn't feel right that the user of the `shared_ptr` wrapper needs to know which pointer type is wrapped, and how that pointer is supposed to be deleted. What would be the best way to achieve the same kind of usage as with the `unique_ptr` example of above.

In other words, that I could end up with:

```
SurfaceShPtr surface(IMG_Load("image.png"));
```

Instead of of something like

```
SurfaceShPtr surface(IMG_Load("image.png"),
                     [=](SDL_Surface* ptr){SDL_FreeSurface(ptr);});
```

Or, just slightly better

```
SurfaceShPtr surface(IMG_Load("image.png"),
                     SDL_Deleter());
```

---

Is there a way to do this, without having to create a RAII wrapper class (instead of a typedef), adding even more overhead?

---

If the answer is "this isn't possible". Why not?

Comment: Did a [search on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+shared_ptr+custom+deleter) yield *nothing* helpful?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I did. You can mark it as a duplicate if you find something I missed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely If you want to show me how, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, decltype(&SDL_FreeSurface)> p(IMG_load("image.png", &SDL_FreeSurface);`

Comment: Or see the update to my answer. I decided to just use a single deleter type for everything, instead of a class template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answer provided here was that something close to what I asked could be done through function returns of `unique_ptr` with custom deleter, which can be implicitly converted to a `shared_ptr`.

The answer given was that a deleter defined as a type trait was not possible for `std::shared_ptr`. The answer suggested as an alternative, to use a function which returns a `unique_ptr`, implicitly converted to a `shared_ptr`.

Since this isn't part of the type, it is possible to make a simple mistake, leading to memory leaks. Which is what I wanted to avoid.

For example:

```
// Correct usage:
shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> s(createSurface(IMG_Load("image.png")));

// Memory Leak:
shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> s(IMG_Load("image.png"));
```

The concept I want to express is having the deleter as part of the type (which `unique_ptr` allows), but with the functionality of a `shared_ptr`. My suggested solution is deriving from `shared_ptr`, and providing the deleter type as a template argument. This takes up no additional memory, and works in the same way as for `unique_ptr`.

```
template<class T, class D = std::default_delete<T>>
struct shared_ptr_with_deleter : public std::shared_ptr<T>
{
  explicit shared_ptr_with_deleter(T* t = nullptr)
      : std::shared_ptr<T>(t, D()) {}

  // Reset function, as it also needs to properly set the deleter.
  void reset(T* t = nullptr) { std::shared_ptr<T>::reset(t, D());  }
};
```

Together with a deleter class (Thanks Jonathan Wakely. Way cleaner than my macro (now removed)):

```
struct SDL_Deleter
{
  void operator()(SDL_Surface* p) const { if (p) SDL_FreeSurface(p); }
  void operator()(SDL_RWops* p) const { if (p) SDL_RWclose(p); }
};

using SurfacePtr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Deleter>;
using SurfaceShPtr = shared_ptr_with_deleter<SDL_Surface, SDL_Deleter>;

using RWopsPtr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_RWops, SDL_Deleter>;
using RWopsShPtr = shared_ptr_with_deleter<SDL_RWops, SDL_Deleter>;
```

Instances with `SurfaceShPtr` members are type guaranteed to clean up properly, the same as for `SurfacePtr`, which is what I wanted.

```
// Correct Usage (much harder to use incorrectly now):
SurfaceShPtr s(IMG_Load("image.png"));

// Still correct usage
s.reset(IMG_Load("other.png"));
```

---

I'll leave this up for a while, for comments, etc, without accepting the answer. Maybe there are even more dangerous caveats I've missed (having a non-virtual destructor not being one, as the parent `shared_ptr` is given charge of the deletion).

Comment: This makes sense. There is no problem with object slicing, because your derived type has no additional data or functions, it only serves one purpose: passing a deleter at construction time, once that's done it doesn't matter if the object gets sliced and you only keep the `shared_ptr<T>` base part. Personally I still prefer my suggestion of creation functions returning `unique_ptr`, which can be converted to a `shared_ptr` that still uses the right deleter. I think that's more flexible, you can convert from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` but not vice versa.

Comment: _"My suggested solution is deriving from `shared_ptr`, with the a static deleter as a type trait."_ That's not a type trait, it's a default template argument.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I fixed the incorrect wording. I should add that I totally agree that this way is less flexible, but the restriction is desired, as I would never want to be able to create a shared_ptr with the incorrect deleter. Passing around shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> provides no guarantee on that. Again. Thanks for the help regarding this!

Comment: Your approach doesn't provide a guarantee either. `SurfaceShPtr s; s.reset(new SDL_Surface);` Now `s` has the wrong deleter. So your type isn't foolproof, you need to follow a convention to use it safely, which is also true for my suggestion of "always create the types with the creation functions that return `unique_ptr`", if you do that consistently and never write `new SDL_Surface` then you have the same guarantee: you will never have a `shared_Ptr<SDL_Surface>` that doesn't have the right deleter, because the only way to get one is from conversion from a `unique_ptr` with the right deleter

Comment: Shouldn't adding `void reset(T* t = nullptr) { std::shared_ptr<T>(t, D());  }` retain the guarantee, even when using `s.reset(new SDL_Surface);`?

Comment: That just creates a temporary and discards it, but yes you could replace `reset()` to do the right thing. You can certainly make it harder to misuse, but I could still get around your guarantee if I was sufficiently motivated e.g. `static_cast<shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>&>(sp) = std::make_shared<SDL_Surface>();`

Comment: I meant, `void reset(T* t = nullptr) { std::shared_ptr<T>::reset(t, D()); }`, (but for some reason unbeknownst to me, it still worked when I tested it). As for being able to circumvent safeguards if seriously inclined, that's not the kind of errors I want to protect against ;)

Comment: Why doesn't `SurfaceShPtr SurShPtr = nullptr` works?

Comment: Why does `shared_ptr_with_deleter` have a default template parameter `std::default_delete<T>`?  The whole point of this subclass is to enforce use of a deleter other than `std::default_delete<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

A typedef is a static, compile-time feature.

A deleter passed to a `shared_ptr` is a dynamic, run-time property. The deleter is "type-erased" and is not part of the `shared_ptr` interface.

Therefore you can't declare a typedef to represent an alternative deleter, you just pass one to the constructor.

> What would be the best way to achieve the same kind of usage as with the `unique_ptr` example of above.

You could use functions to create the resources and return them in a `shared_ptr`

```
shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> create_sdl_surface(const char* s)
{
  return shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>(IMG_load(s), SDL_FreeSurface);
}
```

But I would have those functions return a `unique_ptr` instead, which can be converted to `shared_ptr`, as below.

I would get rid of the macro and do something like this:

```
// type with overloaded functions for freeing each resource type
struct SDL_deleter
{
  void operator()(SDL_Surface* p) const { if (p) SDL_FreeSurface(p); }
  void operator()(SDL_RWops* p) const { if (p) SDL_RWclose(p); }
  // etc.
};

// a unique_ptr using SDL_deleter:
template<typename P>
  using SDL_Ptr = std::unique_ptr<P, SDL_deleter>;

// typedefs for the common ptr types:
using SurfacePtr = SDL_ptr<SDL_Surface>;
using RWopsPtr = SDL_ptr<SDL_RWops>;
// etc.
```

To answer the shared_ptr part of your question, define functions that create resources and return them in a `SDL_ptr`:

```
SurfacePtr createSurface(const char* s) { return SurfacePtr(IMG_load(s)); }
RWopsPtr createRWops([...]) { return RWopsPtr([...]); }
// etc.
```

Then you can easily create a `shared_ptr` from the result of those functions:

```
shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> s = createSurface("image.png");
```

The `shared_ptr` automatically acquires the right deleter from the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Sorry about the const char* usage. I was a bit quick with my example, and made a mistake. I've fixed it now.

Comment: If you want to take a quick look at my alternative answer, I'd appreciate it. Cheers.

Comment: Note that the deleter is only called if `p != nullptr` is true, so there is no need for the `if(p)`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, that's not true in general. For `shared_ptr` the deleter is used if it "owns" a pointer, whether null or not. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f8f1932108bc489). When converting from a `unique_ptr`, it's true that `shared_ptr` won't own anything if the `unique_ptr` doesn't own anything (at least, since my [LWG 2415](https://wg21.link/lwg2415) issue was resolved for C++17), but the deleter defined above is safe to use directly with `shared_ptr`. For cases where the `shared_ptr` isn't converted from a `unique_ptr` the null checks may be needed.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I'm confounding that with the delete operator overload...