# Typedef alias of std::shared_ptr with custom deleter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I want to make an alias for `std::shared_ptr` with custom deleter.

This code works, but only for unique pointer. I get error about invalid amount of template arguments for line marked with [ 1 ].

I have noticed that template and ctor arguments for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` differ as listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

I have noticed that this question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331315/typedef-a-shared-ptr-type-with-a-static-custom-deleter-similar-to-unique-ptr), but I can't figure out how to solve my problem

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(T* p) const noexcept {
       p->Drop(); // SFINAE
    };
};

template <class T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter<T>>;

//template <class T>
//using my_shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T, Deleter<T>>; // [1] does not work
//using my_shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<my_unique_ptr<T>>; // this is pointless

template <class T>
using my_shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;


template <class T, class... Args>
my_unique_ptr<T> my_make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return my_unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template <class T, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> my_make_shared(Args&&... args)
{
    return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Deleter<T>{}};
//  return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Deleter<T>()}; this also works
}

class MyClass{
    public:
      MyClass() 
      {
          std::cout << "Default ctor\n";
      }
      ~MyClass()
      {
          std::cout << "Default dtor\n";
      }
      void Drop()
      {
          std::cout << "Custom deleter\n";
          delete this;
      }
};

int main()
{
    {
        my_unique_ptr<MyClass> p1(new MyClass);
        my_unique_ptr<MyClass> p2 = my_make_unique<MyClass>();
    }

    {
//      my_shared_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass) // [2] does not work
//      my_shared_ptr<MyClass> p(my_make_unique<MyClass>()); // [3] does not work
        std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p1 = my_make_shared<MyClass>(); // [4] works
        my_shared_ptr<MyClass> p2 = my_make_shared<MyClass>();
    }
}
```

**For [ 2 ]**
How do I make it know to use my deleter?

**For [ 3 ]**
If [ 2 ] isn't possible, then how do I create a function than can create a `my_shared_ptr<T>` for me?

**Error for [ 1 ]**

```
main.cpp:15:51: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
 using my_shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T, Deleter<T>> // does not work
                                                   ^~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/memory:82,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:343:11: note: provided for 'template<class _Tp> class std::shared_ptr'
     class shared_ptr;
           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

**Error for [ 2 ]**

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/memory:82,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = MyClass; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Deleter<MyClass> > __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:117:32:   required from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = MyClass; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Deleter<MyClass> >]'
main.cpp:48:45:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:885:39: error: cannot convert 'MyClass*' to 'std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Deleter<MyClass> >*' in initialization
         : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p)
                                       ^
```

**Edit**
Added `my_make_shared` function, now [4] compiles fine.

**Edit**
I have noticed (by observing errors) that my alias for `shared_ptr<MyClass>` is not really an alias for `shared_ptr<MyClass>`, but an alias for `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<MyClass>>` - it's trying to create a pointer to pointer (fisrt I thought it's just redirecting constructor)

**Edit**
Commented out alias for pointer to pointer. The idea of using [ 1 ] and [ 3 ] is indeed pointless *or maybe even pointerless*.

Added new (correct) alias for shared_ptr

**Edit**


## The whole code works now. All problems solved.

**Edit**
Last, minor question:
Why I can't change `return my_unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));` to `return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};`?

I'm getting this error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'my_unique_ptr<T> my_make_unique(Args&& ...) [with T = MyClass; Args = {}; my_unique_ptr<T> = std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Deleter<MyClass> >]':
main.cpp:56:61:   required from here
main.cpp:26:63: error: converting to 'my_unique_ptr<MyClass> {aka std::unique_ptr<MyClass, Deleter<MyClass> >}' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer) [with _Tp = MyClass; _Dp = Deleter<MyClass> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = MyClass*]'
                     return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
                                                               ^
```

Understood that ctor of `std::unique_ptr` is explicit, but ctor of `std::shared_ptr` is not.

**Thanks SO for all your help!**

Comment: (1) Please post the error messages, (2) it looks like you forgot a closing bracket `>` in [1], (3) I don't see a `typedef` anywhere.

Comment: `shared_ptr` actually type-erases its deleter. It is not a template argument. Look at duplicating the interface of [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), perhaps.

Comment: @Rakete1111 fixed, although it still doesn't compile. I pasted the error

Comment: Correction for your last edit: Constructors taking a single pointer for both smart pointers are `explicit`.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed, that `Deleter<T>{}` can be substituted by `Deleter<T>()` - which one suits convention better?

Comment: `{}` avoid Most vexing parse, forbid narrowing of the parameters. `()` works pre C++11, look like a function call (So can be substituted by function or MACRO in some case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do a `my_make_shared`, something like:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> my_make_shared(Args&&... args)
{
    return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Deleter<T>{}};
}
```

Usage:

```
 std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p(my_make_shared<MyClass>());
```

And for [3], it should be:

```
 std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p(my_make_unique<MyClass>());
```

Note that `std::shared_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T/*, D*/>>` is mostly pointless.

Comment: Pls add example code how to create an object with it, I can't get it to work with both [2] and [3]

Comment: @Xeverous: Ex added.

Comment: Can you explain problem in my last question?

Comment: @Xeverous: constructor of `std::unique_ptr` taking an pointer is `explicit`, so disallows this syntax. It is to avoid implicit conversion which would be really dangerous. In your case, you might use `return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...), {}}` (which build a default `Deleter`).

Comment: So implicit constructor for `std::shared_ptr` is considered safe? I thought that both or none would be explicit, not just unique

Comment: The one taking only a pointer is `explicit` too, the one taking an `std::unique_ptr&&` is not explicit and is safe (owner ship transfer)

Comment: Ahh, indeed; my_make_ functions are calling different overloads.